# How to count number of consecutive null values in array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I have an array of customers that has a nested array of payments.

```
"customer_1" => array:4 [▼
 0 => "211.79"
 1 => "206.20"
 2 => "0.00"
 3 => "0.00"
 4 => "220.90"
]

 "customer_2" => array:4 [▼
 0 => "0.00"
 1 => "0.00"
 2 => "0.00"
 3 => "0.00"
 4 => "220.90"
]
```

I need to count, for each customer, the amount of consecutive payments, starting from the top of the array that are 0.00.

So I would need it to return something like:

```
"customer_1" => 0
"customer_2" => 4
```

I've tried a bunch of while and foreach loops but can't get it to work:

```
@php($count = 0)

    @foreach($array as $arr)

        @if($arr = "0.00")
            @php($count = $count + 1)
        @else
            @continue
        @endif

    @endforeach
```

Comment: Not really clear, according to your example.`"customer_1" `'s value is 211.79+206.20+220.90?

Comment: I need a count of consecutive "0.00" payments, not a sum of payments.  Customer 1 has no consecutive "0.00" payments from the top of the array, therefore customer_1 = 0.

Comment: But I think `customer_1` have two consecutive '0.00',am i wrong?

Comment: Correct, however not from the start of the array.  Their first payment is 211.79 so therefore count should be 0.

Comment: I have post my answer, plz check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the first element, if it is `0.00`, then just calculate the consecutive `0.00`, or just break the loop:

```php
$count = 0;
if ($array[0] == "0.00") {
    foreach($array as $item) {
        if($item == "0.00") {
            $count += 1;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
return $count;
```

For blade:

```php
@php($count = 0)

@if($arr[0] == "0.00")
@foreach($array as $arr)

   @if($arr == "0.00")
      @php($count += 1)
   @else
      @break
   @endif

@endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Appreciate the blade syntax! Great job.

Answer (score 0):

you are assigning value to variable inside if condition , you need to compare "0.00" inside if condition .

```
@php($count = 0)

  @foreach($array as $arr)

    @if($arr == "0.00")
        @php($count = $count + 1)
    @else
        @continue
    @endif

 @endforeach
```

Comment: Hey still doesn't work, it outputs count as the same amount of payments.  customer_1 => 5, customer_2 =>5

Comment: @Dexx please look this refernce https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-consecutive-pairs-of-same-elements/  hope this is your requirements :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum = 0;

foreach($items as $item) {
    $sum += $item;
}

echo $sum;
```

Try this @dexx

Comment: Hey thanks for responding however that is summing the values, I need a count of consecutive "0.00" payments from the beginning of the array.